# How to produce a hidden data variable in a <td>

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a table that you can click on a cell and update the info in the cell, which I will do via AJAX.  For my query to work, I need the new info entered in the cell and also a hidden variable which is the id of the previous data in the cell, but I dont know how to hide that piece of data such as one would do within a form with a hidden input. I would be much appreciative if anyone could help me out. Thanks

Comment: You may be interested in [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), but you should probably include your code so we have some idea of what you're working with.

Comment: some code and a jsFiddle will help answer the question more easily.

Comment: Use `.data()` to store meta data in each cell. If you can provide your code I can give you a more practical example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use HTML5 data attributes to store the data on the td itself:

```
<td data-id="123456" data-another-variable="98765"> ... </td>
```

Comment: While correct, this doesn't exactly tell the OP _how_ to use HTML5 data elements.

Comment: It gives them more than enough to Google "html5 data attributes jQuery" and learn a lot more than parroting code from SO. Quite often its gaining the single missing piece that allows you to learn a whole new area of knowledge...

Comment: The whole point of this site is to become a single point of knowledge. Basically telling someone "here's the topic you want, go search for it" hardly accomplishes that goal. This would make for a very good comment, but seems a bit light for an answer. If the OP's google-fu was strong, s/he probably wouldn't need to ask the question here. Just my take on it.

Comment: thanks for the help, this is what I was looking for and wasnt very knowledgeable on the new html 5 attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Let assume you have HTML like this

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span data-id="21">Tony<span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span data-id="43">345.22<span>
    </td>
</tr>

<input type="text" id="txtEdit" style="display:none" />
```

Each cell has some values now when you click on it. a hidden textbox move to that perticular cell (inside TD) and hide the span so now it would be like this.

```
<td>
    <input type="text" id="txtEdit"/>
    <span style="display:none" data-id="21">Tony<span>
</td>
```

When user out focus from textbox update value using ajax and update new value in span. in case user press escape move out textbox to body and show span as it is. you dont need to take hidden field. So Simple!